# Formatting Print Output in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc, pretty-print

I have a connection to a MSSQL database with pyodbc and im looking to format the results into a table, I have tried prettytable without good results (it put my headers on 2 rows and was still jumbled up).  My description field has some long text in it.  I would like the output to have the headers and wrap the text in those columns so it is easy to make out.  The current output looks to be in tabbed format but it doesn't include the column headers.

```py
#Select IP
input_var = input("Enter IP Address: ")

cursor.execute("SELECT IP,Location,Description,Project,OS,DNS,NETBIOS,MAC FROM [IPAM].[dbo].[Sheet1$] WHERE IP=?", input_var)
row = cursor.fetchall()

for line in row:
    print(*line)
```

Comment: We don't write code for you, we debug code. Please include the code you tried to use to format it so we can see if we can help you get it working. Properly. You also already asked a question about this project yesterday here.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch08s11.html) might suffice.